# Prove that $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(Re^{i\phi})Re(\frac{Re^{i\phi}+z}{Re^{i\phi}-z}) d\phi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on disc $D_{R_0}$ centred at the origin and
>    of radius $R_0$. $0<R<R_0$, $z\in D_R$. Prove that $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}
>  f(Re^{i\phi})Re(\dfrac{Re^{i\phi}+z}{Re^{i\phi}-z}) d\phi$.

The hint given in the book is :

> if $w=\dfrac{R^2}{\bar z}$, then the integral $\dfrac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-w}$
>   around the circle of radius $R$ centered ar the origin is zero.

I used the hint to got $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}f(Re^{i\phi})\Big(\dfrac{Re^{i\phi}}{Re^{i\phi}-z}+\dfrac{Re^{i\phi}}{Re^{i\phi}-\frac{R^2}{\bar z}} \Big)d\phi$, but I do not know how to make that ugly thing in the bracket to the desired form. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Questions 1- Do you have some extra '>' in the statement you want to prove? 2- What is $R$ how is it related to $R_0$?

Comment: sorry for typo.

Comment: Are you sure about the thing you have derived? Could you a little explain your steps please?